# Writing steps to an equation

Tags: equations, lyx, align

I am new to LyX, how do I write steps to an equation, and if I want to do an operation on both sides of the equation, something like

```
x+2=2 \-2
x = 0
```

Comment: You might be interested in reading LyX's Math manual. See Help > Math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

If you don't like the vertical bar, consider replacing `\mid` with `\setminus`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'align*' environment
\begin{document} 
\begin{align*}
x+2 &= 2 \qquad \mid -2\\
x\phantom{{}+2} &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If your systems of equations tend to be more involved than the one you gave in your posting, you may want to look into loading the `systeme` package. One of its very nice features is that it handles many equation-related formatting tasks with ease. Caveat: The package's user guide is available only in French; however, the document features a lot of more or less self-explanatory examples and should thus be usable even if you don't understand French.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme} % for '\systeme' macro

\begin{document} 
\[
\sysdelim.. % no delimiters on either side
\systeme{x+2=2 @ \qquad\mid-2,
         x=0}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: how do you write comments within the equations?

Comment: @Ethan - what do you mean by "comments"? Could you give an example?

Comment: like explanatory text

Comment: @Ethan -- Do you mean something like replacing the "`-2`" fragment with a text string, e.g., "`\text{Subtract 2 from both sides}`"? (The `\text` macro requires the `amsmath` package.)